# Grading a quiz through AngularJS and json objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a bunch of questions in a quiz I'm displaying. All the values come from the json object with the structure of:

```
sections: [
 subSections:[
  "questions":[
     "title":"a",
     "number":"b",
     "name":"c",
     "answers":[
       {
        "answerKey": "true",
        "answerLabel": "true"
       },
       {
         "answerKey": "false",
         "answerLabel": "false"
       }
     ]
   ] 
 ]
]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to grab these values from the array in a previously written function:

```
function getRandomFiveQuestions(questionArray){
            var returnArray = [];
            var loopLength;
            loopLength = questionArray.length >= 5 ? 5 : questionArray.length;
            outerLoop:
            for(i=0; i<loopLength; i++){//do this 5 times
                var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * questionArray.length); //get a random whole number between 0 and the array length
                if(returnArray.length != 0){ //if the list of questions we're compiling already has items
                    for(j=0; j<returnArray.length; j++){//loop through the return array
                        if(returnArray[j]==questionArray[randomIndex]){ //if the random item is already in the return array
                            i--; //redo this step in the outer loop, which will get a new random number and try again
                            continue outerLoop; //skip everything else in the outer loop
                        }
                    }
                    //if we've gotten to the end of the inner loop and a duplicate wasn't found, we'll run this code
                    //which will add the random item to the return array
                    returnArray.push(questionArray[randomIndex]);
                }
                else{ //if there are no items in the return array yet
                    //add the item to the return array
                    returnArray.push(questionArray[randomIndex]);
                }

                //console.log(returnArray[i]);
            }

            //when we're done looping, return the resulting array
            return returnArray;
        };
```

And then on submit compare answers so that if any of them are true, the true ones get combined and display a score in %.

The options to be selected are displayed in radio buttons.

I would love some general directions on how to accomplish that with JS. I've had a lot of help with the previous functionality that grabs an array and now I am only thinking of general concepts and can't really come up with anything solid. STILL LEARNING JS.

Comment: How is the return of your function looking like? Also your markup? A fiddle of all this would be greap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY approach since I'm not quite sure of ure setup ( I may be just tired):

```js
angular.module('quizApp', []);

angular.module('quizApp').controller('QuizCtrl',
  function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    this.selectedAnswers = {};

    this.questions = [{
      'title': 'Question 1 ?',
      'answers': [{
        'title': 'Answer 1',
        'correct': false,
      }, {
        'title': 'Answer 2',
        'correct': true,
      }]
    }, {
      'title': 'Question 2 ?',
      'answers': [{
        'title': 'Answer 1',
        'correct': false,
      }, {
        'title': 'Answer 2',
        'correct': true,
      }]
    }]

    this.validate = function() {
      ctrl.correctAnswers = 0;
      ctrl.totalQuestions = ctrl.questions.length;

      for (var answer in ctrl.selectedAnswers) {
        answerObj = ctrl.selectedAnswers[answer]
        if (answerObj.correct) {
          ctrl.correctAnswers += 1;
        }
      }



    }
  })
```

```html
<div ng-app='quizApp' ng-controller='QuizCtrl as qCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='question in qCtrl.questions'>
    <p>{{ question.title }}</p>
    <div ng-repeat='answer in question.answers'>
      <input type='radio' name='{{question.title}}' ng-model='qCtrl.selectedAnswers[question.title]' ng-value='answer'>{{ answer.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button ng-click='qCtrl.validate()'>Validate answers</button>

  <p ng-if='qCtrl.totalQuestions'>
    {{ qCtrl.correctAnswers }}/{{ qCtrl.totalQuestions }} were correct
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Applying this to my setup, the ng-if gets completely commented out and the function assigned to the button is not being called. :(

Comment: How does your markup look? Note that im using "controller as" approach instead of $scope.

Comment: Here's the markup for the section. I wasn't the one who wrote this originally and I'm not comfortable with Angular enough yet to go and change everything, but here's a fiddle of what the quiz section looks like and what the controller for that section does in its fullness:

https://jsfiddle.net/Varyampir/2014n453/

Comment: Had to change the this.selectedAnswers to var selectedAnswers and the correctAnswers returns 0 every time I console.log it so it's not grabbing the values. :(Other vars console.log entirely nothing.

Comment: Your example does not define an angular module, nor is there any ng-app tag in the markup.

Comment: The ng-app is defined in the main index.file and ng-modules are all associated with it. Everything else works in the site other than pulling the selected values and passing them on the function.

Comment: Well, its hard to test anything in the jsfiddle if there is no actual angular app around.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just unsure of how to translate the project I'm working on into the jsfiddle. It's got a HUGE json file and super weird connections to everything.

Comment: UPDATE: this solution would work with my current code (which I cannot post in its entirety due to its hugeness and company restrictions) for the exception of how ng-model currently works. When I set it to ng-model="answer.answerKey" as per the json structure, it automatically makes it so that once you click on the  radio button, all the rest of the questions are selected without your actually clicking on any of them.